# Log4J2 : How to Pass Application Name in TCPSocketServer implementation from client to server

Tags: sockets, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am running a Log4J2 TCPSocketServer on an edge node in a cluster. All the data nodes send log events to the TCPSocketServer on the edge node and also log locally in the data node using the log4j2.xml configuration file as shown below. The Application Name is stored as a System property and is accessible in the data node or client's log4j2.xml configuration using ${sys:ABC.appname}. How can I send the same appname to the edge node where TCPSocketServer is running using the log4j2.xml. I would be using the same Application Name in the log4j2-server.xml to log events into separate log files just like I am doing locally on data node.

Sample snippet from data node or Client - log4j2.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" >
    <Appenders>
    <Socket name="socket" host="localhost" port="12345" >
    <SerializedLayout />
    </Socket>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="/var/log/${sys:ABC.appname}.log" >
    <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
    <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
    </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Sample snippet from edge node or Server - log4j2-server.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="/var/log/data/${hostName}-<**This is where I would like to see the appname from data node**>.log" >
    <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <Async name="AsyncFile">
    <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
    </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <Root level="WARN">
    <AppenderRef ref="AsyncFile"/>
    </Root>
    </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used ThreadContext to resolve this issue. Its pretty easy to add Thread Context into the codebase and later use Routing to segregate the log events based on the ThreadContext. I followed the example on this link to do the same https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files